# Typing "PartOf" in Excel changes automatically to part of

Tags: microsoft-excel

Okay, I encountered a super weird thing. I haven't had the chance to try it on different machines, but when I type in "PartOf" within my header line of my Excel table, it automatically changes to "part of"! I tried using single quote prefix and it still changes (i.e. 'PartOf -> 'part of). Is this happening for you guys/gals too? Or is my computer insane?

I even tried copy and pasting from [WordPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad) to make it work, but no, it changes it still. How can you type in "PartOf" within a cell?

Comment: Maybe it is spell checking?

Comment: but I can confirm it does it on my version also

Comment: Has to be spell checking, but how can I turn it off? :/

Comment: **Always** turn off "autocorrect as I type" .  It will invariably do more harm than good.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can turn it off or remove that specific change:

Go to Excel Options --> Proofing --> Auto correct Options.

Uncheck the `Replace Text as you Type` or find that specific line in the list and delete it.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Aside from switching it off permanently for all future, as described in the other answer:
if you want it only *once* not done, you can type CTRL+Z (undo) right after the change happens - this will undo the 'correction', not your typing.

Comment: While true, this is a very poor way to work, because your workflow & thought processes are being continually interrupted.

Comment: Right - except if it is a one time case, and you know it. Normally, autocorrect does a useful job, but if a single time I need the uncorrected form, this is the right approach.